# Are there plural forms to interrogatives like "who"?

Tags: plural-forms, interrogatives

In Greek there are different singular and plural forms of τίς (who):

Singular:

τίς - who?
τίνος - whose?
τίνι - to whom?
τίνα - whom?

Are there plural English forms?
τίνες - 
τίνων - 
τίσι(ν) - 
τίνας -

I am learning Greek, as an English speaker, but find my understanding of English to be limiting.

Comment: Hi Peter. Welcome to ELL! No. In English we only have those four words. They are used in both the singular and the plural.

Comment: Thank you @OldBrixtonian. I am a student and learning, thank you for the response.